Trouble understanding a summation step in the proof of partial summation formula
PROOF. [...] we see that
$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{x<n\leq y}a_{n}f(n)&=\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2}f(n)\Big(A(n)-A(n-1)\Big)\\&=\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2}f(n)A(n)-\sum_{n_1-1\leq n\leq n_2-1}f(n+1)A(n)\\&=\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2-1}A(n)\Big(f(n)-f(n+1)\Big)+A(n_2)f(n_2)-A(n_1-1)f(n_1).\end{aligned}$$ [...] Question: I don't see how \begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2}f(n)A(n)-\sum_{n_1-1\leq n\leq n_2-1}f(n+1)A(n) =\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2-1}A(n)\Big(f(n)-f(n+1)\Big)+A(n_2)f(n_2)-A(n_1-1)f(n_1).
\end{aligned}
My attempt:
I expressed this by term: $$\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2}f(n)A(n)-\sum_{n_1-1\leq n\leq n_2-1}f(n+1)A(n)=$$$$(f(n_1)A(n_1)+f(n_1+1)A(n_1+1)+f(n_1+2)A(n_1+2)+\cdots+f(n_2)A(n_2))
-\left(f(n_1)A(n_1-1)+f(n_1+1)A(n_1)+f(n_1+2)A(n_1+1)+\cdots+f(n_2)A(n_2-1)\right).$$ But I just don't see anything. I suppose $A(n_2)f(n_2)-A(n_1-1)f(n_1)$ part should come from simplification of the terms and the remaining sum $\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2-1}A(n)\Big(f(n)-f(n+1)\Big)$ should probably be the "remainder" after simplification. But I don't really see it, and the change in indices of the sum doesn't help. Would be greateful if someone could point me to the right direction.

It's all there in your equation, breaking it into more steps:
\begin{aligned}
&\hspace{6mm}\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2}f(n)A(n)-\sum_{n_1-1\leq n\leq n_2-1}f(n+1)A(n) \\
&=\left[\left(\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2-1}f(n)A(n)\right)+ f(n_2)A(n_2)\right]-\left[\left(\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2-1}f(n+1)A(n)\right) + f(n_1)A(n_1-1)\right]\\
&=\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2-1}[f(n)A(n)-f(n+1)A(n)] + f(n_2)A(n_2)- f(n_1)A(n_1-1)\\
&=\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2-1}A(n)[f(n)-f(n+1)]+A(n_2)f(n_2)-A(n_1-1)f(n_1),
\end{aligned}
where in the first step I just pick off the terms where the endpoints don't match. Note that $n\le n_2$ is one more step than $n\le n_2-1$ and $n_1-1\le n$ is one more step than $n_1\le n$.

Thanks for the help. Just to double-check, am I understanding correctly that this is because we can write: $\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2}A(n)f(n)=\left(\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2-1}A(n)f(n)\right)+A(n_2)f(n_2)$, and $\sum_{n_1-1\leq n\leq n_2-1}A(n)f(n+1)=\left(\sum_{n_1\leq n\leq n_2-1}A(n)f(n+1)\right)+A(n_1-1)f(n_1)$?

Welcome. Yes, exactly.
